# Replace Fragment inside Fragment - (Behind)

Tags: android, gridview, android-fragments

When I click on my gridview item, it should replace the current fragement by the new fragment. It seems to happen but I don't see the new fragment. The new fragment is behind the other one.

I can't figure out why it's not working.

Any idea ?

Thanks

```
 public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) 
        {             
                    View rootView = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.TypesFragment, container, true);
                    return rootView;
        }

        public override void OnActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState)
                {
                    base.OnActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

                    typesList = FullDAO.GetTypesOfResto (); 

                    GridView mGridView = Activity.FindViewById<GridView> (Resource.Id.list);
                    mGridView.Adapter = new TypeOfRestoAdapter (Activity, typesList);

                    mGridView.ItemClick += delegate (object sender, AdapterView.ItemClickEventArgs args) {

                        OnGridItemClick((GridView)sender,args.Parent,args.Position,0);
                    };
                }

                public void OnGridItemClick(GridView l, View v, int index, long id)
                {
                    //Get the selected type
                    TypeResto currentTypeResto = typesList[index];

                    // Create a new fragment and a transaction.
                    FragmentTransaction fragmentTx = this.FragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
                    RestoByTypeFragment aDifferentDetailsFrag = new RestoByTypeFragment();
                    aDifferentDetailsFrag.typeId = currentTypeResto.id;

                    // Replace the fragment that is in the View fragment_container (if applicable).
                    fragmentTx.Replace(Resource.Id.types_fragment, aDifferentDetailsFrag);

                    // Add the transaction to the back stack.
                    fragmentTx.AddToBackStack(null);

                    // Commit the transaction.
                    fragmentTx.Commit();
                }
```

Comment: If you grid view replacing a base fragment ? if yes, assuming that you have a fragment base with id (Container). And your grid view is replacing the fragment base. Now, on click of the grid item, you will replace the fragment base with its id(Container). Is this how the flow is ?

Comment: Yes, I have a fragment base :  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <fragment
        class="lpresto.TypesFragment"
        android:id="@+id/types_fragment"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
</LinearLayout>

Comment: Then, I replace my fragment base with another one :                   fragmentTx.Replace(Resource.Id.types_fragment, otherFragment);

Comment: I usually use a frame layout instead of the fragment tag to replace the content with other fragments. So, basically instead of fragment tag, u can try using frame layout and set the id to container(whatever ID) and replace your base fragment with the frame layout's id and that fragment will have two things, help and other item. and on click of any of the items, replace the frame container again.

Comment: Thank you very much. Replacing the fragment tag by a fragment layout solved my issue.

Comment: Np.. glad I was able to help .. :)